# Remove 5 last characters in my URL after .html

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, web

I keep getting 5 random characters appended to the end of my website URL like this

```
https://www.imotionsecurite.com/index-eng.html/sdsds
```

To fix this issue, I want to write a RewriteRule in my .htaccess file to forawrd all files ending in .html with 5 characters following to the same url without the last 5 characters.

I have tried using this `RewriteRule ^(.*).html\/.{5}$ ^(.*).html [R=301, L]` but it keeps crashing my site.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule at top of your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+\.html)/[^/]{5}/?$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Wow! It worked like a charm, don't know what I would have done without man! Quick question, might you know a rule that would remove everything at anytime after the .html? Once again, thanks anubhava!

Comment: To remove anything after `.html` use; this rule: `RewriteRule ^(.+\.html).+$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]`

Comment: Also anubhava, everything works perfectly, except since I use anchors in some URL's. therefore the removing of everything after .html breaks my anchors. Is it possible to have a RewriteCond where if after .html there is a # do nothing, but if not, removing everything. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually URL part starting with `#` is not even sent to web server.